# Not getting push notifications to the Android device

Tags: php, android, notifications, push

I'm trying to send push notifications to an Android device using PHP and according to the result I get from Google, it should be working.

**Result from Google:**

```
stdClass Object
(
    [multicast_id] => 6.72923727292E+18
    [success] => 1
    [failure] => 0
    [canonical_ids] => 0
    [results] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [message_id] => 0:1380125340880858%35261526f9fd7ecd
            )

    )

)
```

According to the documentation, if I'm getting a message id back, it should at some point be sent to the device. I've previously gotten error messages like "MismatchSenderId" and "InvalidRegistration", but after a few fixes, this is the result I'm getting, and what I would expect to be a successful result.

*"When a 3rd-party server posts a message to GCM and receives a message ID back, it does not mean that the message was already delivered to the device. Rather, it means that it was accepted for delivery."*

If this is the result I get from Google (using my API key and sending to http://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send), am I at least doing the right thing in the PHP? Or should I expect a different result?

If it helps, in order to get this result I'm sending the following information:

```
{"registration_ids":["some_device_token"],"data":{"message":"a simple message","title":"a title","link":"some_url"}}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your were in correct track in push notification using PHP. There may be a delay in receiving the notification in device and also scrutiny with some other android device.

**I am 100% sure your were correct in PHP Coding **

**Please check with Google device token id generated from the device was an accurate because i too face same issue then i rechecked with application**